# In an intermediate pipeline, which one has better performances between $addFields and $project

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database-performance

I would like to know if there is a performance difference between a `$addFields` or `$project` intermediate stage in a mongodb aggregate

Let's suppose this data :

```
{"_id":"5c9b88648a2b5700118e5a05","values":[5,8,2],"piv":1}
{"_id":"5c9b88658a2b5700118e5a06","values":[9,8,2],"piv":1}
{"_id":"5c9b88658a2b5700118e5a07","values":[1,8,2],"piv":2}
{"_id":"5c9b88658a2b5700118e5a08","values":[5,3,2],"piv":2}
```

Is there a performance difference between these two aggregates (this is just an example) :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    // This is the stage that will change
    $addFields: {
        v: {
            $reduce: {
                input: '$values',
                initialValue: 0,
                in: {
                    $sum: ["$$value", "$$this"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$piv',
        vals: {
            $sum: '$v'
        }
    }
}])
```

and

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    // This is the stage that will change
    $project: {
        piv: 1,
        v: {
            $reduce: {
                input: '$values',
                initialValue: 0,
                in: {
                    $sum: ["$$value", "$$this"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$piv',
        vals: {
            $sum: '$v'
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: `$addFields` **merges** data into the existing document and `$project` specifies a **completely new** document. "Performance" is completely relative to whatever you are actually doing. Basically use them for what they are designed for. `$project` when you can specify "everything you want" in a simple manner, or `$addFields` when you don't actually want ( or it is not practical ) to specify **every field** in the desired output, and simply want to ***add/overwrite some additional output***. "Which is better?" simply does not come into the equation. Just use which one is most appropriate.

Comment: Thx @NeilLunn, so, their is no need to worry about perfs for `$addFields` and `$project`